Getting 'Request failed with status code 400' error when trying to create job from node js to salesforce for attachment insert
I want to create a job for inserting zip file as a attachment in salesforce and I am following this documentation. I am using this function
export const getRequestFile = async (attachments) => { 
try { const baseDir = 'attachments'; fs.mkdirSync(baseDir, { recursive: true });
const requestFilePath = path.join(baseDir, 'request.txt');
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(requestFilePath);
stream.write('Name,ParentId,Body\n');

attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
  const attachmentFilePath = path.join(baseDir, attachment.Name);
  fs.writeFileSync(attachmentFilePath, attachment.Body, 'binary');
  stream.write(`${attachment.Name},${attachment.ParentId},${attachment.Body}\n`);
});

stream.end();

const output = fs.createWriteStream('attachments.zip');
const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });

output.on('close', () => {
  logger.info('attachments.zip created successfully.');
});

archive.on('error', (err) => {
  logger.error(err);
});

archive.pipe(output);
archive.directory(baseDir, false);
await archive.finalize();

const jobInfoXML = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                    <jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
                      <operation>insert</operation>
                      <object>Attachment</object>
                      <contentType>ZIP_CSV</contentType>
                    </jobInfo>`;

const filePath = 'job.txt';
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, jobInfoXML);

const sfConn = await sfLogin();
if (!sfConn || !sfConn.accessToken) {
  throw new BadGateway('Something went wrong with Salesforce login.');
}
const apiVersion = '58.0';
logger.info(`${apiVersion}`);
const sessionId = sfConn.accessToken;
logger.info(`${sfConn.instanceUrl}`);
const zipFileData = fs.readFileSync('attachments.zip');
const apiDetails = {
  URL: '/services/async/61.0/job',
  METHOD: HTTP_POST_STR,
  CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'
};
const jobResponse = await sendSfApiRequest(apiDetails, jobInfoXML);
logger.info (`jobResponse----> ${jobResponse}`);
const result = await parseStringPromise(jobResponse.data);
const jobId = result.jobInfo.id[0];
logger.info (`jobId ${jobId}`);
const zipFileName = 'attachments.zip';

const response = await axios.post(
  `${sfOtherDet.instanceUrl}/services/async/${apiVersion}/job/${jobId}/batch`,
  fs.createReadStream(zipFileName),
  {
    headers: {
      'X-SFDC-Session': sessionId,
      'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
    },
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  }
);

console.log('File uploaded successfully:', response.data);
return response;
    } catch (exp) { 
    logger.error(MSG: EXCEPTION: INSIDE ${getRequestFile.name}. ERROR: ${exp.message}); throw    new BadGateway(exp.message); 
    } 
}; 

export const sendSfApiRequest = async (apiDetails, params) => {
  try {
    // Authenticate with SF.
    const sfConn = await sfLogin();
    let sfApiRes = null;
    if (!sfConn || !sfConn.accessToken)
      throw new BadGateway(SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG);
    if (nodeEnv !== TEST_ENV && debugMode === DEBUG_MODE_ON) {
      //logger.info(`REQUEST PARAMS : ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);
      logger.info(`SF API ENDPOINT : ${sfConn.instanceUrl}${apiDetails.URL}`);
    }
    // Axios auth instance create to call SF API endpoints
    const axiosReqInst = create({
      baseURL: sfConn.instanceUrl,
      maxContentLength: Infinity,
      maxBodyLength: Infinity,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": apiDetails.CONTENT_TYPE,
        Authorization: `${OAUTH_STR}${sfConn.accessToken}`,
      },
    });
    logger.info(`Request Details: ${axiosReqInst.defaults.headers}`);
    // If GET request
    if (apiDetails.METHOD && apiDetails.METHOD === HTTP_GET_STR) {
      // Generate the GET request URL iwth params
      const apiUrl = `${apiDetails.URL}?${new URLSearchParams(
        params
      ).toString()}`;
      // Send get request
      sfApiRes = await axiosReqInst.get(apiUrl);
    } else if (apiDetails.METHOD && apiDetails.METHOD === HTTP_POST_STR) {
      // If POST then send post request
      sfApiRes = await axiosReqInst.post(apiDetails.URL, params);
    } else {
      throw new BadGateway(ReasonPhrases.BAD_GATEWAY);
    }
    if (apiDebugMode === API_DEBUG_MODE_ON)
      logger.info(`SF API RESPONSE: ${JSON.stringify(sfApiRes.data)}`);
    return sfApiRes;
  } catch (exp) {
    if (nodeEnv !== TEST_ENV)
      logger.error(
        `MSG: EXCEPTION: INSIDE ${sendSfApiRequest.name}. ERROR : ${exp?.message}`
      );
    throw new BadGateway(
      debugMode === DEBUG_MODE_ON ? exp?.message : ReasonPhrases.BAD_GATEWAY
    );
  }
};

But I am getting error

Request failed with status code 400

here:
const jobResponse = await sendSfApiRequest(apiDetails, jobInfoXML);

what is the error?
I am unable to find the reason why this error happens where there is no error in username, password...
